# How can connect MySQL database + Node JS for React JS front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am a beginner for React JS and Node JS. So please tell me how can connect Node JS (Express or other frameworks) + MySQL for our React JS front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check documentation on Expressjs.com (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql)

Comment: MySQL database data how can display on the react js front. who can help me? please give me a sample project or link.